# C# Program keeps running in Processes after closing form

Tags: c#, tcp, process, dispose

Lately, when using my TCP/IP Server and Client, I has noticed that they both stay open in Processes after I close them.

I fixed the Client staying open by disposing the socket to the server, which closes down all asynchronous threads in the background of my framework.

However, when trying to do so with the server, no matter what I do, the process stays open.

ASSUMING that the TCP/IP server is handling it's own stuff, is there ANY thing else in this code that would keep the process open?

EDIT: UPDATE:
If I put a breakpoint after the Application.Run(new ServerForm()) line in Program.cs, it will break once I press exit or call Application.Exit().

I don't know what it is hanging up the program but it's not exiting the Main.

```
namespace ChatServer
{
    public partial class ServerForm : Form
    {
        private NetLib.Server _server = new NetLib.Server();
        public delegate void ClientConnection(ServerNetworkState ns);

    public ServerForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ServerForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Set up server IP and Port #.
        _server.Ip = "127.0.0.1";
        _server.Port = 5001;
        //Setup events for success/error checking
        _server.NewConnection += new NetLib.Server.NetworkStateEventHandler(_server_NewConnection);
        _server.Started += new NetLib.Server.ServerEventHandler(_server_Started);
        _server.Initialized += new NetLib.Server.ServerEventHandler(_server_Initialized);
        _server.BindFailure += new NetLib.Server.ServerEventHandler(_server_BindFailure);
        _server.BindSuccess += new NetLib.Server.ServerEventHandler(_server_BindSuccess);

        //Initialize Server and add neccesary commands
        _server.Initialize();

        //Clients will call sendmessage on the server,
        //and the server will send the message to the neccesary clients.
        _server.MessageEncoder.FriendlyCommands.Add("sendmessage", SendMessage);
    }

    public void SendMessage(short sender, short[] recipients, string text)
    {
        _server.MessagePump.Enqueue(new Packet(-1, recipients, "receivemessage", text));
    }

    void _server_BindSuccess()
    {
        //Log Bind Success at DateTime.Now
    }

    void _server_BindFailure()
    {
        //Log Bind Failure at DateTime.Now
    }

    void _server_Initialized()
    {
        //Log Initialized at DateTime.Now
    }

    void _server_Started()
    {
        //Log Started at DateTime.Now
    }

    void _server_NewConnection(NetLib.ServerNetworkState ns)
    {
        //Log New Connection with ns.Ip at DateTime.Now
        BeginInvoke(new ClientConnection(AddClientToControl), ns);            
    }

    private void AddClientToControl(NetLib.ServerNetworkState ns)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("ID: " + ns.Id + " IP: " + ns.Ip);
    }

    private void startServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _server.Start();
    }

    private void ServerForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        _server.Dispose();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I have no idea about NetLib.Server, but it seems that you(or your library) don't set the Thread's `IsBackground` property to true.

Comment: The library doesn't use System.Threading.Thread but instead using the Socket AsyncResults.

Comment: may be you should wait to see if it is disposed or not>

Comment: You say `lately` as if this wasn't happening before.  Is it just that you didn't notice or is it that it wasn't actually happening before now?

Comment: I am sure that this has been happening the entire time.

Comment: @KyleUithoven - This may be an obvious question but are you sure the `ServerForm_FormClosing` event handler is assigned to the `Form.FormClosing` event?

Comment: @M.Babcock : It is not a stupid question, I just confirmed that it is indeed assigned correctly.

Comment: Have you tried moving the `_server.Dispose();` call into your form's destructor to see if that would make a difference?

Comment: @M.Babcock : That approach did not help =/

Comment: At this point, I am thinking that the issue may still lie in the Netlib library. I was hoping that there was something that was wrong in this code.

Comment: Use `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()` as a last resort

Comment: Before you go that far, try Application.Exit() in the form close. It will send a term request to all threads.

Comment: @Dracorat : The Application.Exit() is not working (the process is still running), which worries me. =/

Comment: @KyleUithoven - Are you sure that it is not just hanging on _server.Dispose?

Comment: @M.Babcock I've added some more information to the bottom of the question.

Comment: @KyleUithoven - There is nothing else in the provided code that would directly keep the process alive that I can see. That said it does reference code that isn't included (such as the `ClientConnection` class) but they too could just be part of NetLib so may not be relevant to your updated question. It seems that whatever NetLib is seems to be your problem.

Comment: @M.Babcock : Thank you for your time. I will take another look in the library.

Comment: @M.Babcock Also, the ClientConnection is just the name of a delegate used to prevent cross-thread exceptions when using Controls from events.

Comment: @KyleUithoven - I figured as much (since it was passed to an Invoke statement) but without seeing it I didn't want to underestimate your ability to write magic code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6270/discussion-between-kyle-uithoven-and-m-babcock)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there was one thread that was overlooked in the library. Thank you all for trying to trying to find out if there was anything above that would cause the problem.

To answer the question: Nothing in the code above was causing the issue stated. It was a thread that was opened in the Netlib library and was never handled when disposing and closing any connection that was open.

Answer (score 0):

Does NetLib.Server.Dispose() handle all of the 'shutdown' operations? Often times in the .net framework the .Close() calls the dispose but the .Dispose() does not call the close operations.

Comment: It's actually the other way around; in the framework calls to `Dispose()` will always (as far as I am aware) call `Close()`, for example, calling `Dispose()` on a `Stream`.  Otherwise the `using` construct would be useless (no pun intended...).  Still a good question to ask as it was my first thought as well.